# word order in the question "How many people take part in this event"

Tags: wh-questions

I know that questions starting with ***who*** don't need auxiliaries. But what about the question ***How many people take part in this event?***. It's not a WHO-question, why don't we use there DO?

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

First, the rule for "who" applies equally to all "wh-" questions, including *who*, *what*, *when*, *where*, *why*, *how*, *which*, *how much*, ***how many*** etc.

Second, it is not true that "who" questions don't have auxiliaries:

> Who did you see at the party?
> Who do you think will win the election?
> Who does the cooking in your home?

The rule is that questions where *the "wh-" word is the subject* do not use auxiliary verbs, and otherwise do:

> Who likes ice cream?
> What is your name?
> How much sugar spilled?

In your sentence, "how many people" is the subject of the sentence, so it requires no auxiliary verb.

Comment: @dilek22 Rica ederim :)